# Filling HStack swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create a button stack like having a play and record button using SwiftUI, after creating it just does not look anything like what I wanted.

```
var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 8) {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                print("Recordinggg")
            }, label: {
                Text("Record")
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(40.0)
            })
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                print("Recordinggg")
            }, label: {
                Text("Play")
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(40.0)
            })
            Spacer()
        }
        
        
    }
```

What I actually want is something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proper frame, padding you can achieve this. Here is an example code.

Create ButtonStyle.

```
struct ThemeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(40.0)
    }
}
```

Your view

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var phase: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            Button(action: {
                print("Recordinggg")
            }, label: {
                Text("Record")
            })
            .buttonStyle(ThemeButtonStyle())
            
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                print("Recordinggg")
            }, label: {
                Text("Play")
            })
            .buttonStyle(ThemeButtonStyle())
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]